# Replace multiple occurance in string

Tags: javascript

I want to replace some of the words from the user's input using customized characters. The string will be like this

```
var userInput = "five plus five equal to ten multiply 5";
```

This is what I tried to do

```
const punctLists = {
        name: 'star',
        tag: '*'
    },
    {
        name: 'bracket',
        tag: ')'
    }, {
        name: 'multiply',
        tag: '*'
    }, {
        name: 'plus',
        tag: '+'
    }, {
        name: 'double equals',
        tag: '=='
    }, {
        name: 'equal',
        tag: '='
    }]
var matchPunction = punctLists.find(tag => tag.name == userInput);
if (matchPunction) {
    userInput = matchPunction.tag;
}
```

But it is not working. 
I want something like this :

```
var userInput = "5+5 = 10*5";
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is `text` here in `text = matchPunction.tag;` ?

Comment: @SudhirOjha, thanks, that was type, which is edited

Comment: Your question in incomplete add name for `five and ten` as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var userInput = "five plus five equal to ten multiply 5";

const punctLists = [
  { name: "star", tag: "*" },
  { name: "bracket", tag: ")" },
  { name: "multiply", tag: "*" },
  { name: "plus", tag: "+" },
  { name: "double equals", tag: "==" },
  { name: "equal", tag: "=" },
  { name: "five", tag: "5" },
  { name: "ten", tag: "10" }
];

console.log(userInput
    .split(' ')
    .map(x => (f = punctLists.find(item => item.name == x)) && f.tag || x)
    .join(' '))
```

Comment: Thanks mate. This is what I wanted.

Comment: @Fraction, i basically want to replace with the lists in punctLists. equal to will be in the list

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) :

```js
const userInput = "five plus five equal to ten multiply 5";

const punctLists = [
  {name: 'star', tag: '*'},
  {name: 'bracket', tag: ')'},
  {name: 'multiply', tag: '*'},
  {name: 'plus', tag: '+'},
  {name: 'double equals', tag: '=='},
  {name: 'equal to', tag: '='},
  {name: 'five', tag: '5'},
  {name: 'ten', tag: '10'}
];

function ReplaceText(input) {
  return punctLists.reduce((acc, a) => {
    const re = new RegExp(a.name,"g");
    return acc.replace(re, a.tag);
  }, input);
}

console.log(ReplaceText(userInput));
```